# set PGDATA to start postgres server automatically

Tags: ubuntu, postgresql, ubuntu-16.04

I would like to have my PostgreSQL database start itself up. But currently need to run the following:

Terminal 1:

```
sudo su - posgresql
cd /usr/lib/postgresql/9.6/bin/
./postgres -D /usr/local/pgsql/data
```

Terminal 2:

```
$ sudo -u postgres psql
```

I would prefer to only need to run terminal 2 and am unsure why Terminal 1 isn't done automatically.

I was able to confirm that PGDATA is unset by running:

```
$ pg_ctl start -l logfile
pg_ctl: no database directory specified and environment variable PGDATA unset
Try "pg_ctl --help" for more information.
```

I found some useful instructions in the [postgres manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/server-start.html) that say I should be adding `/usr/local/pgsql/bin/pg_ctl start -l logfile -D /usr/local/pgsql/data` to a `/etc/rc.d/rc.local` or `/etc/rc.local` but neither of these dirs exist in on Ubuntu 16.04.

I feel I'm missing a simple command to set PGDATA which will start my server automatically. But I don't know what it is or what file I should store this command in.

Comment: All this is done  by the scripts coming with the ubuntu packages you already installed. The answer to what needs to be done manually with PGDATA is:nothing. Your actual problem is the same as in your previous question: the instance does not automatically start for some reason that still has to be researched and understood.

Comment: After 3 days of research, I have found many instances similar to my problem from years ago. Most people edit the entire init.d/postgresql file which is something I'd like to avoid